# Upstart in Debian/Raspbian

Tags: debian, raspbian

I've switched from sysvinit to upstart but get the below message whenever I attempt to start a service:

> Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket
>   /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused

Upstart does execute all the old sysvinit scripts at startup so it is safe to switch. But Upstart scripts don't seem to work for me.

Does anyone know what may be causing the above error message? The only reference to it I've come across is in relation to running within a chroot or a virtual machine, neither apply.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Have you rebooted the Pi? [serverfault.com/q/236667/upstart-does-not-work](https://serverfault.com/q/236667)
>   - [Steve Robillard](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/56/) on [July 24 at 2:42](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/1230/#comment2113_1230)

Basically, the link says that you should try rebooting the system. Thanks Steve!

Comment: Such a simple answer, but it worked haha